# how to pass [String]' to 'String' value in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a slideshow

I follow this zvonicek/ImageSlideshow library.

But I don't know how to pass array of images to it

I have the following code:

```
let imageSource = [SDWebImageSource(urlString:self.myArray[i])!, ImageSource(image: UIImage(named: "Beach")!)]
slideshow.setImageInputs(imageSource as! [InputSource])
```

`self.myArray[i]` contains that kind of value

and I need to pass that array to imageSource.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson- I get array of images from response and I want to show that images with zooming effect like above images.i don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, what you are trying to do is to transform each element of a `[String]` to a `SDWebImageSource`, so that it forms a `[SDWebImageSource]`. Right? This is precisely the job of the [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018373-map) method.

```
let imageSource = self.myArray.map { SDWebImageSource(urlString: $0) }
```

Or more simply:

```
let imageSource = self.myArray.map(SDWebImageSource.init))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the loading images section in the description of the library, if you have url for the images. You can use the AlamofireSource or KingfisherSource to create the image Source array.

```
  ImageSource(image: UIImage(named: "myImage"))!,
  ImageSource(image: UIImage(named: "myImage2"))!,
  AlamofireSource(urlString: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432679963831-2dab49187847?w=1080"),
  KingfisherSource(urlString: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432679963831-2dab49187847?w=1080"),
  ParseSource(file: PFFile(name:"image.jpg", data:data))
])
```